# Why are TensorFlow LinearRegressor predicting too big numbers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

In a simple example I try to use TensorFlow LinearRegressor but the result can't be correct. Any suggestions?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x_data =np.array([  44.57,  42.71, 119.25, 40.83, 46.87, 71.44, 
113.5, 39.83, 39.48,
77.3,    53.32 ,  21.68 , 113.55  , 40.1  ,  77.39 , 46.01 , 
35.42 ,  93.81,
84.71,   51.7 ,   73.57,  102.21 ,  98.05 ,  99.53 ,  
98.65 ,  50.1,   108.4,
62.06,   48.34  , 71.45  , 53.21 ,  72.57 , 48.14 ,  
71.32 ,  41.01 ,  96.71,
112.09,   54.87 ,  63.17 , 44.95])
y_data= np.array([ 127.42 , 121.09 , 294.53,   96.73,  125.04, 195.08,   
287.84,  106.97,  107.94,
204.45,  116.09 ,  57.64 , 296.82 , 123.5 ,  180.11 , 116.81 ,  
96.73  ,233.71,
237.07,  130. ,   182.61 , 260.22,  238.86 , 238.02 , 
248.05, 101.41,  269.69,
156.43 , 121.27 , 172.64 , 139.62 , 203.87 , 134.78 , 
176.24 , 106.22 , 252.93,
282.96 ,141.95 ,161.  ,  123.42])

features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=1)]
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features,
     model_dir='./linear_estimator')
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x":x_data}, y_data,
     num_epochs=1000)
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=2000)
np.asarray([i for i in estimator.predict(x={'x': x_data})])
```

The result is

array([ 1539.31665039,  1476.55419922,  4059.26489258,  1413.11694336,
        1616.92626953,  2445.9987793 ,  3865.2409668 ,  1379.37365723,
        1367.56335449,  2643.734375  ,  1834.57043457,   766.93310547,
        3866.92822266,  1388.48425293,  2646.77124023,  1587.90698242,
        1230.56567383,  3200.83569336,  2893.77197266,  1779.90625   ,
        2517.87182617,  3484.27929688,  3343.9074707 ,  3393.84741211,
        3364.15332031,  1725.91699219,  3693.15039062,  2129.48681641,
        1666.52893066,  2446.3359375 ,  1830.85864258,  2484.12866211,
        1659.78015137,  2441.94946289,  1419.19055176,  3298.69140625,
        3817.6628418 ,  1886.87243652,  2166.94165039,  1552.13916016], dtype=float32)

Comment: Try using 'batch_size=1' and 'num_epochs=10' in the input_fn

Comment: This works for me quite well with the given code. I obtain [ 114.96195221  110.31800079  301.4190979,... ], which is not perfect, but at least of the right order of magnitude. Which TensorFlow version do you use?

Comment: Considering ml4294's comment, try deleting your model_dir and run your script again. This would clean-up previous training sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works.

I deleted the export directory and have the new version 1.1.0.

Thanks for all answers.